# MongoDB text search, How efficient is it?

Tags: mongodb, lucene, full-text-search

Can mongodb text search be used as a replacement for lucene based search engine (like elasticsearch, solr etc). How efficient is it compared to lucene.

We use solr for text search, text is basically content of book, questions etc.. We use basic solr text search features. Currently we have a size of 400-500 mb data in solr and we are are expecting it may grew by 200 mb per year. In this case, can solr be replaced with mongodb?

I am looking forward to hear from people who have used mongodb as a text search engine. Please share you experiences.

Comment: That depends on what your requirements are.

Comment: you still want to build an information retrieval system, that mongodb is not

Answer (score 2):

I have done some research for a client who was interested to switch to mongoDB FTS in order to decrease stack complexity some months ago when mongoDB introduced FTS and I have done some [very basic benchmarking](https://github.com/nickmilon/mongo_vs_es) results were very encouraging MongoDB been much faster on both reads and writes for **this particular use case** quality of result set were almost same something that is explainable since both used the same 
"snowball" tokenization engine, on the other hand MongoDB index sizes were bigger.

**TL;DR;**: it's worth exploring the possibility depending on your use case provided you don't need some extra features that MongoDB FTS lacks like facets user defined dictionaries etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if MongoDB could outperform Lucene on text search. But since MongoDB has got text indices as well, it could very well be enough for your use case.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

You will have to try it out to be sure.